# How to use subscribe-next RxJS in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I am learning rxjs. I have an observable from an array. I want to put some fruit in function, using subscribe and next. I wrote but not right, may I help you. Thank you so much!

```
const fruits = from([
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "cherry"]);

fruits.subscribe(fruit => this.next(fruit));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const myObserver = {
  next: (item) => console.log('next: ', item),
  error: (err) => console.log('err: ', err),
  complete: () => console.log("Observable completed")
};

of([
  "apple",
  "banana",
  "cherry"
]).subscribe(myObserver);

setTimeout(() => myObserver.next(["Apple"]) ,2000);
```

Answer to Your exercise :D

```
fruits.subscribe(fruit => toConveyorBelt(fruit));
```

Comment: Thank you! I want to complete this lesson: https://www.rxjs-fruits.com/subscribe-next
But I don't know observer what is in this lesson?
Can you explain it to me? Thank you again!!!

Comment: I recommend upvoting/accepting the answer if it fits for you. :)

Comment: @GiangGiang, please vote the answer. and i have added solution to your lesson above.